# Copying setup.py Dependencies with Tox

Tags: python, testing, setuptools, tox

`setup.py` often depends on a couple external files, most notably `README.md` for `long_description`, and maybe `VERSION` for `version`. e.g.

```
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
setuptools.setup(
    name             = 'package',
    version          = open(os.path.join(root, 'VERSION')).read().strip(),
    description      = 'A Simple Package',
    long_description = open(os.path.join(root, 'README.md')).read().strip(),
    # ...
)
```

However, when trying to run tests with `tox` on such a package, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: 
.tox/py36/log/py36-6.log
ERROR: actionid: py36
msg: installpkg
cmdargs: 
['.tox/py36/bin/pip', 'install', '-U', '--no-deps', '.tox/dist/package-0.1.0.zip']

Processing ./.tox/dist/package-0.1.0.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        version          = open(os.path.join(root, 'VERSION')).read().strip(),
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'VERSION'
```

(Or a similar message with `README.md`). Obviously, `tox` only copies `setup.py`, and when it tries to run it, its dependencies are missing and it doesn't work.

I went over the documentation, but I can't seem to find a way to tell `tox` to copy these files. Is there a way to do it?

**EDIT**

Here's my directory structure and relevant files:

```
$ ls
package/   tests/   README.md    VERSION   setup.py    tox.ini

$ cat tox.ini
[tox]
envlist = py36
[testenv]
deps     = pytest
commands = pytest tests

$ cat setup.py
import os
import setuptools
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
setuptools.setup(
    name             = 'package',
    version          = open(os.path.join(root, 'VERSION')).read().strip(),
    description      = 'A Simple Package',
    long_description = open(os.path.join(root, 'README.md')).read().strip(),
    packages         = setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

(The same happens if I use a relative path, e.g. `open('README.md')`.)

Comment: By default `tox` runs in the same directory where `tox.ini` (and hence your README and VERSION) reside so there should be no problems. Can we see your `tox.ini`?

Answer (score 11):

Turns out it's not a `tox` problem, but a `setuptools` one (or rather, me not using it correctly). I'm posting the answer here just in case somebody else runs into similar problems in the future.

`tox` creates a source distribution (i.e. `python setup.py sdist`), and then installs it in a virtual environment, where it then runs the tests. **It's this distribution that's missing the `VERSION` and `README.md` files**, because `setuptools` doesn't include any non-standard files by default. To wit:

```
# create a source distribution
$ python setup.py sdist

# extract it
$ cd dist/
$ tar xfz package-0.1.0.tar.gz

# check it out
$ ls package-0.1.0
package    package.egg-info   PKG-INFO   setup.cfg   setup.py

# no VERSION or README.md :(
```

To include non-standard files, add a `MANIFEST.in` file like this:

```
include VERSION
include README.md
```

Which tells `setuptools` to include these files in the distribution, and makes `tox` work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

What version of `setuptools` were you using?

I had a similar issue and upgrading `setuptools` fixed it.

It seems that  including `README.md` is done automatically as of [version 36.4.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v36-4-0). However the `VERSION` file would have to be included in the `MANIFEST.in` file.